# CentOS, YUM Errors?

Tags: centos, python, yum

I am using a Media Temple DV server with CentOS upon trying to install ImageMagick via yum, I get the following error:

```
There was a problem importing one of the Python modules
required to run yum. The error leading to this problem was:

   /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so: undefined symbol: rpmdbCheckTerminate

Please install a package which provides this module, or
verify that the module is installed correctly.

It's possible that the above module doesn't match the
current version of Python, which is:
2.4.3 (#1, May 24 2008, 13:47:28) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20070626 (Red Hat 4.1.2-14)]
```

Can anyone shed some light on what I might be able to do to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `rpm -V -f /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/rpm/_rpmmodule.so` say? It would be good if you could also run `rpm -V python yum`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `rpm` and `rpm-python` versions have gotten out of sync. This can happen if you've built your own rpm but not the Python bindings, or vice versa. Run `rpm -q rpm rpm-python` and compare the returned versions, and then `rpm -V rpm rpm-python` to verify the integrity of the packages' files.

Comment: The first shows:

rpm-4.4.2-48.el5 
rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5

and the second: 
.M.....T c /etc/cron.daily/rpm 
Unsatisfied dependencies for rpm-python-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386: popt = 1.10.2.3-18.el5, rpm = 4.4.2.3-18.el5, rpm-libs = 4.4.2.3-18.el5

Comment: And there you have it. Your system is half-updated from an older version. Download and run `rpm -Uvh` against all of these at once: http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/popt-1.10.2.3-18.el5.i386.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/rpm-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/CentOS/rpm-libs-4.4.2.3-18.el5.i386.rpm

Comment: when trying to install those packages, I get: rpm = 4.4.2-48.el5 is needed by (installed) rpm-build-4.4.2-48.el5.i386 rpm = 4.4.2-48.el5 is needed by (installed) rpm-devel-4.4.2-48.el5.i386 - So i try installing them and I get another list of dependencies. Can I just downgrade something?

Comment: If you can force those three packages in then you can use yum to update all the others. Since forcing a package is a **bad** thing to do in the general case, you'll need to refer to the man page on how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much! That second comment (upgrading packages) did it for me and saved a bunch of time searching.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and just to add to the fracas, if you are on Media Temple, make sure developer Tools and Root are turned on ;)